# Why is CodeMirror failing with the examples that are part of the downloaded zip file?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am new to CodeMirror and having difficulty getting it to work -- I am specifically looking to get it to work with Groovy.

The following are the steps I have taken:

1. Downloaded CodeMirror-master.zip
2. Unzipped it.
3. Attempted to open "CodeMirror-master/mode/groovy/index.html"

When I open that file, the Groovy code in that file is not formatted.  That file references "lib/codemirror.js".  The file structure in the zip file does not contain "codemirror.js" in the "lib" directory.  However, it does contain "codemirror.js" in the "src" directory.  So, I copied everything from the "src" directory to the "lib" directory and it still doesn't display the formatted code from the example.  When I open the Chrome browser developer tools it shows 4 errors, but I am so new to this type of development that I don't know what to do.  I don't understand why "CodeMirror is not defined" is being thrown -- I assumed that the example code from CodeMirror would work...

The errors I see are as follows:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (codemirror.js)
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
   at matchbrackets.js:10:9
   at matchbrackets.js:11:3
3. Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
   at groovy.js:10:9
   at groovy.js:11:3
4. Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
   at index.html:76:20

What took me down the path of trying out the examples was that I was unable to get it running with my own code after trying to follow the instructions and I have been banging my head against this for too long.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to modify and contribute to codemirror codebase OR are you just trying to use codemirror in your own application? If you just want to use codemirror in your own app, you don't need to download the master branch. Download codemirror using npm and Just follow the getting started guide here - https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html . You can also google codemirror get started to find other many guides.

Comment: I was trying to use codemirror (ie i do not want to modify or contribute).  I was thinking that they provided two ways to use it: 1) download the zip file or 2) leverage npm.  I tried the first approach.  However, from what you are saying, it sounds like the zip file is only for contributors.  If that is true, then it was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

After banging my head against for too long, I have finally found the answer:

the zip file that is currently being distributed is faulty (ie files are not where they are supposed to be and other files are missing).

I had to use the instructions for downloading it via NPM (ie `npm install codemirror`), then copy that directory structure to my project.